# Python newline whitespace, how to print with out a whitespace

Tags: python

```
a="Python"
b="Learn Python"
print(a,"\n",b)
```

Output :

```
Python
 Learn Python
```

Why output newline has a whitespace 
How to avoid this, I don't need whitespace. My code has anything wrong, please help me

Python 3.6.0

Comment: use `strip()` for removing whitespaces.

Comment: Briefly: the `print` function puts a separator between each passed argument, and the default is a space. The tidiest fix is to specify a new separator, `print(a, b, sep='\n')`.

Comment: @ChandaKorat - That is not what's happening at all.